# View available items to install via apt-get?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am installing a bunch of applications via `apt-get` by just copying and pasting commands, but I want to understand how do people come up with the list of which packages to install? Say for example, I'm installing "java8". The command would be:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Where can I get a list of all the available "java" versions that i can choose from? And how about other applications? How do I list out what can be installed in a particular apt-repository?

Comment: Too many questions.  Also, that list is potentially infinite for the different packages that can be installed - a full packages list is HUGE (the compressed Packages list in gzip form seems to be almost 2MB - that could easily expand to be huge).  Typically, we use `synaptic` or the web page at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ for specific searches and such.

Comment: try `apt-cache <word>` to see a list of packages mentioning <word>.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to update the local repository cache by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now lets say you want to search for all java related packages. The command for that is:

```
apt-cache search "java"
```

Consider that you want to install the `vim` editor and by doing `apt-cache search vim` you have found the package you are looking for and the package is `vim-common`, now you can simply install the latest version of the package along with the dependencies by:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-common
```

That's it. Now if you want to check for other versions available of `vim-common` as you are willing to go for an older version, then you need to do:

```
apt-cache showpkg vim-common
```

this will show the available versions along with the dependencies. here is a sample output:

```
$apt-cache showpkg vim-common

Package: vim-common
Versions: 
2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: dc8579ec9ee0dc36b43d271645170c36
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: dc8579ec9ee0dc36b43d271645170c36

2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: dc8579ec9ee0dc36b43d271645170c36
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: dc8579ec9ee0dc36b43d271645170c36


Reverse Depends: 
  vim-common:i386,vim-common
  vim-nox,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
  vim-gtk,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
  vim-athena,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
  vim-tiny,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
  vim-gnome,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
  vim-dbg,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
  vim,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1
  vim-common:i386,vim-common
  vim-nox,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2
  vim-latexsuite,vim-common 1:7.1.314
  vim-gtk,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2
  vim-athena,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2
  vim-addon-manager,vim-common
  vim-tiny,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2
  vim-gnome,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2
  vim-dbg,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2
  vim,vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2
Dependencies: 
2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 - libc6 (2 2.3.4) vim (16 (null)) vim-gnome (16 (null)) vim-gtk (16 (null)) vim-athena (16 (null)) vim-nox (16 (null)) vim-tiny (0 (null)) vim-common:i386 (0 (null)) 
2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2 - libc6 (2 2.3.4) vim (16 (null)) vim-gnome (16 (null)) vim-gtk (16 (null)) vim-athena (16 (null)) vim-nox (16 (null)) vim-tiny (0 (null)) vim-common:i386 (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 - 
2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2 - 
Reverse Provides:
```

As you can see there are two versions available, one is `2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1` **(latest)** and the other is `2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2` **(old)**. Now to install the older version you need to issue the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-common=2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2
```